# It is possible to use a wildcard for the URL when mocking axios?

Tags: javascript, axios, axios-mock-adapter

I would like to know if it is possible to mock certain URLs using wildcards, e.g. all URLs that start with `/auth`. Can I do something like `/auth*`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, per [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-mock-adapter) you can use a regex as the URL. One of their examples is similar to your use case:

> Using variables in regex
>
> ```js
> const usersUri = '/users';
> const url = new RegExp(`${usersUri}/*`);
>
> mock.onGet(url).reply(200, users);
> ```

Comment: But const url = new RegExp(`${usersUri}/*`); does create a regex that matches an arbitrary number of slashes after the userUri, it is not a wildcard match. It happens to work only because it performs an infix search.

Comment: @Martin that's true, but it is quoted from the docs.